# Jquery: change event to input file on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events

I have a form to upload files, and it should fire the submit after the file selection.

On FireFox/Chrome it goes well, and submits the form after file selection, but I can't do this on Internet Explorer.

Already tried with click/propertychange but nothing happens. Some code I already tried:

```
$("#attach").attr("onChange", "alert('I changed')");
```

```
$("#attach").live($.browser.msie? 'propertychange': 'change', function(e) { ... });
```

This input file is created on the fly; because of it I use `.live()` to bind the event.

Any suggestions?

Comment: For elements that already exist, IE's attachEvent() works: $('#attach')[0].attachEvent('onpropertychange', function() { ... })

Comment: I had the same issue, this thread solved my issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150256/jquery-change-event-on-file-input-element-does-not-fire-if-the-file-selection

Answer (score 43):

I know this is several months late, but I just ran into the exact same behavior in IE7; in all other browsers, the change event for file inputs happens after file selection. In IE7, it happens only if you trigger the file select again, or on blur.

Here's how I ended up fixing it:

```
var $input = $('#your-file-input-element');

var someFunction = function()
{
    // what you actually want to do
};

if ($.browser.msie)
{
    // IE suspends timeouts until after the file dialog closes
    $input.click(function(event)
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            if($input.val().length > 0) {
              someFunction();
            }
        }, 0);
    });
}
else
{
    // All other browsers behave
    $input.change(someFunction);
}
```

Technically you could/should filter the hack condition to just IE7, since IE8 behaves properly on the change event, but it also has the same behavior as IE7 on suspending timeouts while browser-related chrome is visible (I guess it considers it blocking I/O), so it works as-is.

Comment: Thanks for this. There is still no fix within the jQuery core.

Comment: this worked for me perfectly, but I want to understand what the settime did? and how it solved the problem? can't understand it

Comment: Hi Amr: Didn't notice your comment until just now. It works because IE seems to consider a dialog like the file dialog to essentially be blocking I/O: all javascript execution halts while it's open. This means that if you essentially let the click handler complete so IE pops the dialog, and then immediately call your callback (eg by setting a timeout of zero), then it should happen as soon as the dialog closes.

Comment: I discovered the same solution many months ago. I think this should be marked as correct answer, because the perfect solution doesn't exist (I talked about this workaround with the jQuery team in the bug tracker, and they said that it was interesting because they recognized that jQuery can't handle the input type file change event on old IE).

Comment: Doesn't work on IE10 :/
The callback is being called after button is clicked, but before file is dialog is shown.

Comment: This is really not working on IE10 and IE11... @d-sauer solutions is working perfectly...

Answer (score 12):

This is really late, but I was having the same problem, and I solved it by using a styled `<label>` tag with a slight workaround for Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/djibouti33/uP7A9/

**The Goals:**

1. allow user to upload a file by using standard html file input control
2. hide standard html file input control and apply own styling
3. after user selects file to upload, automatically submit the form

**The Browsers:**

- Firefox, Chrome, IE8/9, Safari
- IE7 didn't work, but it might if you add that browser to the workaround detailed at the bottom

**The Initial Solution:**

1. Hide the file input by positioning it offscreen. Important not to display:none as some browsers won't like this.
2. Add another styled element to the page (link, button).
3. Listen for a click on that element, then programmatically send a click to the file input to trigger the native 'file explorer'
4. Listen for the file input's onchange event (occurs after a user chooses their file)
5. Submit the form

**The Problem:**

1. IE: if you programmatically send a click to a file input in order to activate it (2), programmatically submitting the form (5) will throw a security error

**The Workaround Solution:**

1. Same as above
2. Take advantage of the accessibility features built in to the  tag (clicking on a label will activate it's associated control) by styling 
   a  tag instead of a link/button
3. Listen for the file input's onchange event
4. Submit the form
5. For some reason Mozilla browsers won't activate a file input by clicking on it's .
6. For Mozilla, listen for the click on the label and send a click event to the file input to activate it.

Hope this helps! Check out the jsfiddle for details on the html/js/css used to make it all work.

Comment: This was the only solution i could get to work for our fancified "click this image to upload a new one" thing we're building. Thanks so much!

Comment: Very clever but simple solution. Thank you. Used with IE8 and primefaces 5.

Answer (score 11):

Format it like this:

```
$("#attach").change(function() { 
  alert('I Changed');
});
```

**Update:** After answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993946) on this earlier, we realized this was fixed as part of the [jQuery 1.4.2 event re-write](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/02/19/jquery-142-released/), just update to the latest version to resolve the `change` event issue with `<input type="file" />` in IE.

Comment: No, only on firefox/Chrome, IE8/IE7. I think there's a important information, this input file, is created on the fly, because of it I use .live() to bind the event. Thanks

Comment: Only one, this is the code: 'var e = $("<div id=\""+id+"\" class=\"inner-center compose hidden\">"+$("#compose").html()+"</div>");
    $(".middle-center").append(e);' The input file is inside the $("#compose").html(), but I tried putting it on the a simple html file and didn't work either

Comment: @cmedeiros - Try using `$("#attach").live('click change', function() {`

Comment: No... it submit the form, before I can select a file, thanks Nick for your help, I will try with swfupload

Answer (score 3):

I used the following solution. I tried to make it as self-contained as possible.

```
(function($) {
    if ($.browser.msie == false)
        return;

    $('input[type=file]').live('click', function(e) {
        var self = this;
        var blur = function() {
            $(self).blur();
        }
        setTimeout(blur, 0);
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

This has always worked for me in IE6 ad IE7.

```
$('#id-of-input-type-file').change(function(){});
```

Comment: Works only when I click in any place of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a [problem with a race condition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/958a24b7-775e-434b-9fd4-58f72ecbb759) with input fields in IE. By using setTimeout the function that is executed will then register that a change happened. When the UI code is performed in the onChangeEvent, that event hasn't fired yet as it appears to IE.

I solved a similar situation by doing the following inside my change handler:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie) { setTimeout(DoSomeUIChange, 0); } else { DoSomeUIChange(); }
```

The DoSomeUIChange is executed after the current code on the event queue and so removes the race condition.

Comment: Timeouts and intervals __do not__ create threads. Everything still runs in a serial way on a single event queue, no matter how many timers you create or how many intervals you set or how many events you have to process at once.

Answer (score 2):

In IE onchange event works fine when it filled out in html tag directly. Like:

```
<input type="file" onchange="uploader.upload()" />
```

Comment: not a pure JS solution, but it works "out of the box";)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with IE (including IE 9). The UI logic is:

1. click on a `div` element triggers the `click` event on a `file-input-element` so that user click on a `div` trigger file open dialog
2. bind the `change` event handler to the `file-input-element` to ensure the `form` is submitted when file open dialog closed

The app (running inside an iframe) works like a charm on Chrome and FF. But soon I found it doesn't work on IE as when user selected a file and close the dialog the form didn't submit.

The final solution is to drop the logic #1 "click on `div` element trigger `click` event on file input element" and let user to click on the `file input element` directly, and then it works.

BTW, the reason we have a `div` element is we want to hide the browser rendered controls because we have everything in the background image. However set `display` to `none` makes the control not able to respond a user interaction event. So we move the `file-input-element` to outside of the view port and use a `div` element to replace it. Since this doesn't work on IE, we end up with move back the `file-input-element` and set it's `opacity` to 0. On IE 8 or less which doesn't support `opacity`, we use filter to make it transparent:

```
#browse {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution
In HTML hide file element (don't use display: none, won't work in IE), prepare onchange event of IE:

```
<div style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
  <input id="ifile_template" type="file" onchange="this.focus(); this.blur();"/>
</div>
```

In javascript for IE bind function to blur, and for FF,CH bind function change():

```
$(iFile).blur(
  function () {
    ...some code...
  }
);

// FF, CH
$(iFile).change(
  function () {
  ...some code...
  }
);
```

Comment: This is only one solution, that is really working! I tried many other answers here, also everything from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201278/jquerys-form-submit-not-firing-for-ie-only-mvc3-app, but nothing is working, except this one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For IE You can use the "onfocus" event to catch the change of uploading file. Once the file browsing dialog is closed the onfocus event is triggered. You can check this by adding this line to your page:

`<input type="file" onfocus="javascript:alert('test');" />`

Once the dialog is closed the alert message is shown.

This solution is only for IE, not for FF or Chrome.

Comment: Do you mean `onfocus="alert('test');"` ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
setInterval(function()
{
    if ($.browser.msie) $("input[type=file]").blur();
},500);
```

Not pretty, but it works. ;D

Comment: Unfortunately this setInterval() solution is still needed with jquery1-6.4 and IE7.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm, at least that it only works after a blur event takes place, similar to a radio and checkbox in IE. I am probably going to have to add some kind of visual element for the user to click and tell me when they have picked their file.

lame.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#attach").attr("onChange", "alert('I changed')");
```

It works in IE, but if you want to emulate "live" behavior, you should add "onChange" attribute to each new element when create its.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't seem to recognise the `propertychange` event.  I added it to the DOM node using IE's `attachEvent()`.

```
var userChoseFile = function($input) {
    // ...
}

var $input = $(/* your file input */);
$input[0].attachEvent('onpropertychange', function() { 
    userChoseFile($input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uP7A9/531/

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="PicturePath" id="fileUpload" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.tif" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("input[type=file]#fileUpload").on("change", function () {
    alert('hi')
});
```

it works for all browsers, tested.