# Blobstore upload with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-app-engine, blobstore

This is the minimal declaration for the HTML in order to upload a file in Blobstore in the `upload_url`. What is required with this solution is required to click the Submit button in order the content to be submitted and get redirected. How can I do the post in the background with javascript or jQuery without losing the enctype?

```
<form id="upload_file" action="{{upload_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) allows you to submit multipart forms in the background with Ajax.

Example:

```
$('#upload_file').submit(function() { 
    var options = { 
        clearForm: true        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
    }; 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
    return false; 
});

$('[name=submit]').click(function(){
    $('#upload_file').submit();        
});
```

Making this work silently requires that you replace your 'submit' input with a 'button' input:

```
<form id="upload_file" action="{{upload_url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: P I have this working but what I want to avoid is clicking the submit button. Since I have chosen the file I would like to be automatically submited - updated without clicking any button.

Comment: Try this: $('[name=file]').change(function(){ $('#upload_file').submit(); });

Comment: no luck when I select the file it doesn't look like it triggers .change()

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?  Looks like the .change trigger will only work properly on the file input with 1.4.2 or above.  Check out this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993946/any-alternative-to-jquery-change-to-detect-when-user-selects-new-file-via-dialo).