# How to fire change() in dynamic generated multiple-select?

Tags: jquery, forms, events, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery(mobile) to generate a select menu which hides/shows columns of an HTML table.

Looks like this:

```
 container = $('<select name="toggleCols" id="toggleCols" multiple="multiple"><option value="default" data-placeholder="true">Edit</option></select>');

 $('.tableRows').each( function(i) {
     if ( $(this).is(".toggle") ) {
         var toggle = $('<option value="'+i+'">sometext'+i'+</option>');
     container.find("#toggleCols").append(toggle); 
     });
```

This creates the select menu, which contains one option for each table column. Selecting this option should hide/toggle the respective table column.

However, I cannot get the change event to fire:

```
 $("#toggleCols").change( function(){
    console.log( "change" ) 
    // do stuff
    })
```

If I use *live('change'...* and have 10 columns, I get 10 console.logs every time I select a single option. So this doesn't work either.

**QUESTION**
Is there a way to use change without live and get a single console.log?

Comment: Show a _testcase_, rather than arbitrary snippets of code that you're not using.

Comment: you might need to bind or trigger the event

Comment: @PhillPafford: thx I will try that. I didn't manage to setup a working fiddle, seems I can't fire widget-factory plugins from the Javascript window jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have removed the event binding from the loop adding the options. Then using *live* works fine and fires once only.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of jQuery ? There was a problem with this which was fixed after jQuery 1.4.2.

See related issue here: [Any alternative to jQuery change() to detect when user selects new file via dialog box in IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993946/any-alternative-to-jquery-change-to-detect-when-user-selects-new-file-via-dial)

ps. I tried to write this as a comment/question under your post but am not allowed to for some reason. Hope this helps.