# jQuery insert file input onChange error

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<label>File Upload: </label>
<input type="file" name="file[]" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#property_enquiry input[type=file]').change(function() {
    $('<input type="file" name="file[]">').insertAfter("input[type=file]");
});
```

What I want to happen is once the first file is added a new input is added underneath the current one. The above code works when adding the first file to create a second input, however when adding a second file a third input isn't created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#property_enquiry input[type=file]').live('change', function() {
    $('<input type="file" name="file[]">').insertAfter("input[type=file]:last");
});
```

This will automatically work with newly added file inputs.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgmcz/

Comment: Thanks, just tried that. It seems to do it in multiples, once the first input is filled it adds a second form. When adding a second file to the input it then duplicates the first two inputs (including file names) and adds a new field at the bottom of that.

Comment: use `.insertAfter("input[type=file]:last");`

Comment: Bingo, works like a charm. Thanks a lot, saved me hours of messing! :)

Comment: Works in Firefox. But in my IE7, the change events happens after clicking on "submit". Then the new input appears, and you need a second press to submit the form (jquery 1.4.4). Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie