# What is the workaround for onchange with file inputs?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, onchange

As some of you may know already, Internet Explorer's `onchange` event is fundamentally broken prior to version 9. Instead of triggering when a change occurs, it triggers when the input field loses the focus and has changes.

This lead to various workarounds for checkboxes and radio buttons ("use `onclick` instead") and text fields ("use `keyup` instead").

However, I'm having that problem for a file input, and I can't figure out what I do to be notified that a new file has been selected, right after it did, and not when the user clicks elsewhere. I can't attach myself to a mouse event because it's not related to the mouse; and I can't attach myself to a keyboard event because it's not related to the keyboard either.

I'd be willing to use IE-specific stuff if it can solve the problem.

---

Additional infos:

I use jQuery 1.6 and the `live` method to attach the event.

```
$(".upload").live("change", function() { /* stuff here */ });
```

Comment: some chatter about this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c8JuC/1/ works on IE9 with IE7 emulated.

Comment: @pimvdb, I use `live` because I generate a bunch of inputs on-the-fly, and the event isn't fired at the right moment with it (jquery 1.6).

Comment: You'll experience problems with `onchange` event only if used on checkboxes and radios. I'm not sure what's the issue.

Comment: @duri, the issue is that I have an `<input type="file">` with an `onchange` event that fires only when the user clicks somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `onFocus` event, combined with a check to ensure that there is a value. This works because after the user selects a file and the OS file selection dialog box is removed, focus is returned to the input element.

Comment: This would, of course, be the IE-only exception code. It does not work at all in Firefox.