# Javascript validation (safari and firefox)

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I have some javascript to validate an image name before upload. It ignores the file path and works correctly on IE and Chrome, but I get an incorrect file alert regardless when using this in firefox or safari.

```
function validate(elem){
    var alphaExp = /^(?:[\w]\:|\|\\)(\\[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.]+)+\.(jpg|jpeg|pjpeg|bmp|png|pdf|doc|docx|pub|pubx|id|psd|ai|eps|gif|tiff|zip|rar)$/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
        return true;
    } else{
        alert("File name or type is not suitable! \n\nPlease ensure the file type is one we accept and is named without spaces or special characters.");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that for security reasons, FF and Safari won't let you access the file's name. Try adding a `console.log(elem.value)` to see exactly what you get.

Comment: Besides, this is a very poor and Windows-centric way to ignore the file path.

Comment: @NullUserException - Hi, thanks. console.log returns the image. It's also without the file path. Exactly how I want it basically. This is being ignored somewhere along the line else I shouldn't get the alert

Comment: Please give some examples of valid and invalid input strings. e.g. is: `"\\\file.doc"` supposed to be valid? How about: `"|\file.doc"` or just: `"file.doc"`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the change event to trigger the `validate` function in Firefox and Safari:

```
document.getElementById("fileUpload").addEventListener("change", validate);
```

**References**

- [Methods: The input type=file object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535263#methods)
- [States of the type attribute: File Upload state (type=file)](https://developers.whatwg.org/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#file-upload-state-(type=file))
- [Upload files using input type="file" field with .change() event not always firing in IE and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214947/1113772)
- [Jquery: change event to input file on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/113772)