# Upload files using input type="file" field with .change() event not always firing in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have simple piece of code to upload files:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").change(function () {
        $('form').submit();
    });
});

<form class="attachmentsUpload" action="/UploadHandler.ashx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="file" name="file" />
</form>
```

While I click on input and then select a file in dialog box, I'm submitting this file using ajax. This is not important part here. Important part is, that while I select the same file second time in the dialog box, just after submitting the first file, the .change() event does not fire in IE and Chrome. But while I choose different file, the event fires and works properly. Under Firefox it is firing all the time.

How to workaround this, to work as expected (as in Firefox) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150256/jquery-change-event-on-file-input-element-does-not-fire-if-the-file-selection

This may be helpful!

Comment: try using live - $('.attachmentsUpload input.file').live('change', function(){ $('form').submit();
});

Comment: @Jason: unfortunately, this changes nothing

Comment: from jQuery 1.7+ you should use now .on('change', f)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Description

This happens because the value of the input field (the selected filepath) does not change if you select the same file again.

You can set the value in the `onChange()` event to an empty string and submit your form only if the value is not empty. Have a look at my sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/TmUmG/).

#### Sample

```
$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").change(function () {
    if ($(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val() == "") {
        return;
    }
    // your ajax submit
    $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val("");
});
```

### Update

This, for any reason, does not work in IE9. You can replace the element to reset them.
**In this case you need jQuery `live()` to bind the event, because your input field will dynamically (re)created.**
This will work in all browsers.

I found this solution on the stackoverflow answer [Clearing input type='file' using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043957/clearing-input-type-file-using-jquery)

```
$(".attachmentsUpload input.file").live("change", function () {
    if ($(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val() == "") {
        return;
    }
    // get the inputs value
    var fileInputContent = $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val();
    // your ajax submit
    alert("submit value of the file input field=" + fileInputContent);
    // reset the field
    $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").replaceWith('<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />');
});​
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [jQuery.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)

### Check out my updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmUmG/1/)

**Note:** [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is now **removed** from later versions of jQuery. Please use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `live`.

Comment: This helped for Chrome, but not for IE (IE9)

Comment: @JarekWaliszko you are right. My answer is updated.

Comment: @dknssck: Thanks for the effort, but for some reason this works in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't submit a file to the server in IE (IE9, ContentLength equals to 0 at server side).

Comment: @JarekWaliszko i think is happens because the ajax request is async. So you could try to save the value of the field in a variable before resetting it. Submit your variable then. my answer is updated

Comment: Doing this check: `if ($(".attachmentsUpload input.file").val() == "") { return; }`wasn't actually needed, because it makes some trouble in IE. I've written an answer of what is working for me, based on your clues.

Comment: for a general solution, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8863458/1188448. works in all browsers.

Comment: Note that as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated, but .on() or .delegate() can be used instead. See the jQuery documentation at http://api.jquery.com/live/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Based on dknaack answer, the clue is **usage of jquery live to bind change event and resetting the input field after submit**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").change(function () {
        $('form').submit();  /* sync submit */
        $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").replaceWith('<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />');
    });
});
```

The resetting must be performed **after submit** event is done. When the submit is **async**, reset the field for example in **ajax success** event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".attachmentsUpload input.file").change(function () {
        $('form').submit();  /* async submit */
    });
});

.ajaxForm({
    ...
    success: function (result) {
        // reset the field - needed for IE to upload the same file second time                    
        $this.find("input.file").replaceWith('<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />');
    }
});
```