# jQuery alert not work in ie on onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

Alert not come when onchange event in internet explore ?

**i am use below code:**

```
<input type="file" onChange="readURL(this)"  />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js " > </script>
<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        alert('asf');
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            //alert(e.target.result);
            $('#photoview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can check below link for solution in IE. 

[Stack Over Flow Solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214947/upload-files-using-input-type-file-field-with-change-event-not-always-firin

Comment: You can check below link for solution in IE. 

[Stack Over Flow URL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214947/upload-files-using-input-type-file-field-with-change-event-not-always-firin

Answer (score 0):

IE9 doesn't have the FileReader.

See compatibility table at end of [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader). Note that this document also proposes a solution for compatibility with IE.

Comment: Other than the [proposed solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3699/crossbrowser_image_preview.html) I don't know.

Comment: @dystry Ok. Thank you. I ll use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

for IE you have to use `FileSystemObject` activex component

for more details check this link :

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0600__MS-JScript/FileSystemObjectGetFile.htm