# Jquery change event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html:

```
<form id="fileuploadform">
    <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" />
</form>
```

and jquery:

```
$(':file').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    ...
});
```

The problem is: the change function fires only when the file selection is different than the selection made previously. That is of course the meaning of the 'change' event.
I want my function to be called with the file dialog closes, no matter what.

I tried using 'select'  event -- it never gets called

I also tried:

```
$(':file').bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
    alert('closed');
});
```

and:

```
$(':file').live("dialogclose", function(){
    alert('closed1');
});
```

They didn't work either.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu55W/ - works on FF, maybe a browser-related issue.

Comment: @Chris Dixon This fires for all selection change. I need the event  fires only when the file selection is different than the selection made previously.

Comment: @Codegiant Read the comment. It works in FireFox. If you select a file and Press OK, then go to select the same file again and press OK, the `change` event fires. It doesn't work in Chrome. And I'm not sure about other browsers.

Comment: @Codegiant Your comment completely contradicts what you've said in the question, so which is it that you actually want?

Comment: I don't think there is an event that will always fire when the file dialog closes, best you can do is a click event on the button that opens the dialog, or a change event, which if I remember correctly, should not fire unless the form elements value actually changes.

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214947/upload-files-using-input-type-file-field-with-change-event-not-always-firin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use this code.

```
$('#fileupload').on('change', function () {
    alert('Hi');
    //do your function.
});
```

this function will call only you select different files otherwise not.

Answer (score 11):

I have faced the same issues when I used to work with jQuery dynamic appended HTML.

I would suggest you to use the below solution

```
$(document).on('input','#fileupload', function () {
  console.log('Your Code')
});
```

Comment: This was my ticket out of hell.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old post, but try using 'input' instead of 'change'.  Worked for me. :)

```
$('#fileupload').on('input', function () {
  alert('Hi');
});
```

Comment: would you explain more,  why input instead change?

Comment: I wish I could explain better.  The jQuery implementation of the 'input' event seems to take from the JS implementation. 

Better written details here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384264/1735394