# What is INPUT event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Who are the creator of the 'input' event? Is this exist before JQUERY?Can anyone explain why this event is not yet popular(limited information) though this event is very useful.

```
JQuery.on('input', function() {});
```

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Comment: why would you think it was a good idea to ask this on SO without googling for it?

Comment: as stated..why is limited information or when you search it..the article directly explained the 'input' event is not on the top list?..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did exist before jQuery. It means:

> The value of an element changes or the content of an element with the attribute contenteditable is modified.

Here is a list of events:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events

Answer (score 0):

> Occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user
>   interface.

And this event did exist before jQuery :

```
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    r.innerHTML += "keyup event triggered <br/>";
}, false);
```

You have information on this link : [jQuery 'input' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)