# Capture IE cross button press on text box

Tags: jquery

IE10 shows cross button in the text box which clear the text boxcontent. I want to capture that event so that I can mark text box red. Any idea?

Comment: I doubt *that* "button press" can be captured (as it is not a separate button but rather part of the browsers interface for a textbox), but the underlying/resulting event (maybe a "value change") could probably be captured.

Comment: I already have .on('keyup mouseup', '.myClass', function() {}); binding but its not catching this event.

Comment: Neither keyup nor mouseup are the underlying [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) (or [input event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)). What happens if the user's browser auto-completes the field? Same thing: only binding to the key/mouse events *misses* what actually happens.

Comment: can I have .on(keyup mouseup propertychange',..)? I tried this an didn't capture click on cross button event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("textarea").on('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#f00");
    }
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sLzhgezf/1/

**Edit**: You should actually use `.on` instead of `.bind`. I've updated the answer and the fiddle.