# Event for user selecting continuation in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

When I input some text in an `<input type="text">`, and the text matches some previously input text, the browser will present a dropdown and I can reuse that text.

[image]

But which javascript event will the input receive when that text is selected?

- onkeydown/onkeyup does not trigger
- onchange does not trigger.
- In Firefox, it seems like onselect is triggered, but not in chrome. However, that event is used for other purposes.
- onclick does not trigger.
- onblur is as usually only triggered when the input loses focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an interesting event named [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event):

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rsn87kxq/).

Html:

```
<form>
    <input id="text" name="text" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit" />
</form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#text').on('input', function()
    {
        console.log('Changed to ' + this.value);
    });
});
```