# Trigger input jQuery

Tags: jquery

I made a keyboard plugin. When I click on values of the keyboard it succesfully fills the input box, but it doesn't trigger my event.

In a nutshell:

```
<form>
    <input id='testinput' type='text' name='test' value='' />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
    $('input').keyboard().show();
});

$('#test-input').on('input', function() {
   alert('change'); 
});
```

The code for the keyboard is a bit too big to show it here. It is attached in the fiddle.
When I manually write something in the input it is triggered, but not via the keyboard.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `$("a").trigger("click");` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Tip: A typo here? `$('#test-input')`

Comment: From the documentation: **input**: _Occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user interface._

Comment: I saw it, thanks, forgot to change it back while editing, but that doesn't change a thing unfortunately..

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery 'input' event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are programatically inserting the characters when a user clicks so you will need to manually trigger the "input" event handler also in your plugin

```
click: function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  e.preventDefault()
  this.select()
  this.$element.trigger('input')
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4eg3oexc/)

Comment: Thanks! I had it almost right myself, but instead of input I had the ID of the input. Many thanks my hero!

Comment: Its Failing Buddy,Try the combination some i/p from keybord some from input ,it fails

Comment: @ShekharPankaj what's failing? I couldn't get it to fail - Are you sure the input has the focus when you are using the keyboard?