# on("input") not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code is not working in IE 9 or older versions. But it is working perfectly on Chrome. What could be wrong with this?

I am using Jquery 1.10.2.min.js

```
 $("[id$='txtNewPass2']").on("input", function () {
    if (myPlugin.metReq() == true && $("[id$='txtNewPass2']").val().length > 0) //return true or false
       $("#imgSubmit").removeAttr("disabled").css('opacity', 1);
    else
       $("#imgSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled").css('opacity', 0.5);
 });
```

### update:

I just saw .. My browser in Quirks mode. Does it effect anything?

[image]

Comment: [It should work for IE9, but it's not supported before then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event/17384341#17384341) suggests to use `.on('input propertychange')` to support older browsers. Does that work for you? If you wanted to use a jquery event you could use `.on('keyup')`