# jQuery input event - trigger('change') does not it

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have the following event listener on my `input`s on a HTML page:

```
$('input').on('input', function (e) {
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

I understand the `input` event captures the following individual events `change`, `keyup` and `paste`.

When I update an input value using jQuery, I want to trigger this event so my event code runs. If I run:

```
//Does not work
$('input').val('test').trigger('change');
```

My event does not fire. I expected the `input` event handler to catch the `change` event. If I run:

```
//Does work
$('input').val('test').trigger('input');
```

This *does* work... why does triggering the `change` event not fire my `input` event handler?

Comment: No, `oninput` event does not responds to `onchange` event. They are different. It would be really confusing world where one events trigger other events.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e0xr8u0x/1/ - input event does fire

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event) may be helpful to you

Comment: "why does triggering the change event not fire my input event handler?" Why the hell would one type of event fire another type of event?

Comment: @MauricePerry - reread my question - the input event is fired most definitely when `paste` and `keyup` events are triggered.

Comment: @keidar it does not. If you paste something in the field, or if you type a key that will alter the text, and that will trigger an input event.

Comment: Oh OK - I was under the impression it does. I will go back to the drawing board and do a bit more testing - thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected the input event handler to catch the change event.

That's where you went wrong - the `input` event handler does not catch `change` events.

Comment: I thought it does? Which events does it catch then?

Comment: input event caches the input event. Period