# jQuery updating function with input change from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few functions and events in place that update invoice totals on change, paste, keyup and touchend which works great. However I have coded something that allows you to insert item data from a dropdown select and copies some things to input values however that does not update and now sure what changes I need to make for this to happen. Anyone have any ideas?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9m7q0mp8/ (if you click select product and add your see what I mean, it adds name and value, but I need it to update the subtotal and also the totals at bottom like it does, when you manually enter values in for an item).

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', ".item-select", function(e) {

        e.preventDefault;

        var product = $(this);

        $('#insert').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false }).one('click', '#selected', function(e) {

            var itemText = $('#insert').find("option:selected").text();
            var itemValue = $('#insert').find("option:selected").val();

            $(product).closest('tr').find('#invoice_product').val(itemText);
            $(product).closest('tr').find('#invoice_product_price').val(itemValue);

            //updateTotals('#invoice_table');
            //calculateTotal();

        });

        return false;

    });

// add new product row on invoice
    var cloned = $('#invoice_table tr:last').clone();
    $(".add-row").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        cloned.clone().appendTo('#invoice_table'); 
    });

    calculateTotal();

    $('#invoice_table').on('change keyup paste touchend', '.calculate', function() {
        updateTotals(this);
        calculateTotal();
    });

    $('#invoice_totals').on('change keyup paste touchend', '.calculate', function() {
        calculateTotal();
    });

    function updateTotals(elem) {

        var tr = $(elem).closest('tr'),
            quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', tr).val(),
            price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', tr).val(),
            isPercent = $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val().indexOf('%') > -1,
            percent = $.trim($('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val().replace('%', '')),
            subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

        if(percent && $.isNumeric(percent) && percent !== 0) {
            if(isPercent){
                subtotal = subtotal - ((parseFloat(percent) / 100) * subtotal);
            } else {
                subtotal = subtotal - parseFloat(percent);
            }
        } else {
            $('[name="invoice_product_discount[]"]', tr).val('');
        }

        $('.calculate-sub', tr).val(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    }

    function calculateTotal() {

        var grandTotal = 0,
            disc = 0,
            c_ship = parseInt($('.calculate.shipping').val()) || 0;

        $('#invoice_table tbody tr').each(function() {
            var c_sbt = $('.calculate-sub', this).val(),
                quantity = $('[name="invoice_product_qty[]"]', this).val(),
                price = $('[name="invoice_product_price[]"]', this).val() || 0,
                subtotal = parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(price);

            grandTotal += parseFloat(c_sbt);
            disc += subtotal - parseFloat(c_sbt);
        });

        // VAT, DISCOUNT, SHIPPING, TOTAL, SUBTOTAL:
        var subT = parseFloat(grandTotal),
            finalTotal = parseFloat(grandTotal + c_ship),
            vat = parseInt($('.invoice-vat').attr('data-vat-rate'));

        $('.invoice-sub-total').text(subT.toFixed(2));
        $('#invoice_subtotal').val(subT.toFixed(2));
        $('.invoice-discount').text(disc.toFixed(2));
        $('#invoice_discount').val(disc.toFixed(2));

        if($('.invoice-vat').attr('data-enable-vat') === '1') {

            if($('.invoice-vat').attr('data-vat-method') === '1') {
                $('.invoice-vat').text(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_vat').val(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('.invoice-total').text((finalTotal).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_total').val((finalTotal).toFixed(2));
            } else {
                $('.invoice-vat').text(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_vat').val(((vat / 100) * subT).toFixed(2));
                $('.invoice-total').text((finalTotal + ((vat / 100) * finalTotal)).toFixed(2));
                $('#invoice_total').val((finalTotal + ((vat / 100) * finalTotal)).toFixed(2));
            }
        } else {
            $('.invoice-total').text((finalTotal).toFixed(2));
            $('#invoice_total').val((finalTotal).toFixed(2));
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm checking, however I have noticed that each time you add a new item you create an `input` with the same `id="invoice_product"` andthis is not fine.

Comment: Ahh that i do, ill update that to use a class instead, i did add input to that list but done nothing but let me try with just that.

Comment: So i updated to what you suggested and does not seem to work still: http://jsfiddle.net/9m7q0mp8/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9m7q0mp8/2/)

- The `id` problem is that it must be unique, this will not the solve problem but will prevent others, it an HTML rule ([W3SCHOOLS Id description](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)):

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value
>   must be unique within the HTML document).

The id attribute is most used to point to a style in a style sheet, and by JavaScript (via the HTML DOM) to manipulate the element with the specific id.

- The `input` event should contain all the other events that you have listed alone, with some difference ([input event answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-eventv)):

> Occurs when the text content of an element is changed through the user
>   interface.

- This was another problem: `e.preventDefault;`, you missed the parenthesis:`e.preventDefault();`
- The real problem was that `updateTotals();` was sending the wrong element identifier, this is the correct one:`updateTotals('.calculate');`

  ```
  $(document).on('click', ".item-select", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var product = $(this);

      $('#insert').modal({backdrop: 'static',keyboard: false}).one('click', '#selected', function (e) {
          var itemText = $('#insert').find("option:selected").text();
          var itemValue = $('#insert').find("option:selected").val();

          $(product).closest('tr').find('#invoice_product').val(itemText);
          $(product).closest('tr').find('#invoice_product_price').val(itemValue);

           updateTotals('.calculate');
          calculateTotal();

      });

      return false;

  });
  ```

Comment: Perfect thanks mate, knew was something a little more simple. Appreciate it!