# keypress event not working with the last inserted character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this code:

```
$(".SermeCoopConvertirMayuscula").keypress(function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    regexp = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
    return regexp.test($(this).val());
});
```

It is working fine. But when i type something it doesn't update my last inserted character. How can i make that the last character is added?

I need use the keypress event, i cant use the keyup event.

Comment: Can you not use the https://api.jquery.com/change/ function instead?

Comment: Because I like to see what I'm writing in UpperCase

Comment: Have a look at my latest solution if you can't use keyup event

Answer (score 12, accepted):

True, because when function is called the field is not updated with the value

The event is called in this steps

1. Keydown
2. Keypress
3. updateview
4. Keypress
5. updateview
6. keyup

So if you can change this event to [keyup](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) then you will get the latest value

Or, if you still want to use keypress event that you can do one thing you can use the following code

```
$(".SermeCoopConvertirMayuscula").keypress(function (eventObject) {
    var val = $(this).val() + eventObject.key;
    val =val.toUpperCase()
    var regexp1 = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
    var regexp2 = /^[A-Za-z0-9 ]$/;
    if(regexp1.test(val) && regexp2.test(eventObject.key)) {
      $(this).val(val);
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) instead. when `keypress()` is fired, the most recent character is still not registered in the input, so `$(this).val()` will not include it for the most recent event

```js
$("input").keyup(function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    regexp = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
    return regexp.test($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try `input` which also takes care of various other input scenarios. Take a [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event) for more details.

```js
$(".SermeCoopConvertirMayuscula").on("input", function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
    regexp = /^[A-Z0-9 ]*$/;
    return regexp.test($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="SermeCoopConvertirMayuscula" />
```