# Keyup event for textarea

Tags: jquery, virtual-keyboard

I am using virtual keyboard plugin http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/. 
Here, in the mottie textarea I want to fire a keypress event, so that I can use the physical keyboard to enter the text in the seleted laguage.

I tried something like this

```
$('textarea[name=Notes]').keypress(function (e) {});
```

and like this also

```
$("div.ui-keyboard-preview-wrapper").find('textarea[name=Notes]').keypress(function (e) {});
```

I also tried like this

```
$(".ui-keyboard-preview").keypress(function (e) {});
```

But, its not triggering the event. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Missing relevant context in question but have you tried delegating event?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to do with this code? The plugin does trigger a [`keyboardChange` event](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki/Methods#events) with every change made to the input/textarea. If you want to modify the text, [there are a few examples on the Home wiki page](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/wiki#manipulating-text).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `input` event like below code snippets. It will track the changes in `textarea` field. For the older version of IE `propertychange` event can be used to track the changes.

**Sample code snippets:**

```js
$(document).on('input propertychange', "textarea[name='Notes']", function () {
    alert("Text Updated");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="Notes" rows="4" cols="50">
Your text 
</textarea>
```

**Note:**

> The `input` event will trigger whenever the content of the text area
>   getting changed. But it will not hold the key press information of
>   `event.which`. Instead you can use `keypress` or `keydown` or `keyup`
>   events separately to track the key code.

But for **Virtual keyboard** you could try something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsAbS/3/)

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks John. Now the key event is triggering. But getting another problem.  **e.which** and some other property is coming as undefined. Here In my program, I am also checking if user pressed special key like shift and ctrl. and these properties are also coming **undefined**. How to resolve it ?

Comment: @Bhola Please check this.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event
Regret for the previous comment which I posted without testing. Hope you have understood the concept now.

Comment: Thanks again John.  I got the idea from this link and finally I come up with                      **$(document).on('keypress',"textarea[name='Notes']", function (e) { });**.    And also first time I come to know about the **input** event. +1 from my side. Thank you

Comment: @Bhola You are Welcome.