# How to execute a listener bound to an event and exclude the remaining listeners bound to different events from execution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$input.on('keyup', keyUpListener);

$input.on('input', inputListener);

// IE <= 8 fallback for input event.
$input[0].onpropertychange = function() {
    if (window.event.propertyName === "value") {                
        inputListener(window.event);
    }
};
```

`$input` is a jQuery `input[type='text']`.

Right now `keyUpListener` and `inputListener` are both executed when I type into the `input` or when I copy and paste something (`onpropertychange` is not fired because it is an IE only event).

But how can I tell JS to not fire `inputListener` if `keyUpListener` is executing and vice-versa?

Comment: why do you ned both? Input would be enough http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event

Comment: `input` fires on `keydown` when I type, i.e. when I press and hold down the key the event listener is already fired. I only want to execute the code on `keyup` using `keyUpListener` **when I type**. In the other cases (`copy/paste`, characters inserted from `accent` suggestions in OS X and other cases `keyup` doesn't handle) I want to use the `inputListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the specific event to the textbox?

```
$("#input").on('input', function () {
}
```

For instance the above - this way you can have multiple listeners not executing on the same input

**EDIT**

You are able to bind the paste function to the textbox also..

```
$("#input").bind('paste', function() {
var pasted = true;
});
```

Thus you can then have the below IF statement:

```
if (pasted) {
$input.on('input', inputListener);
} else {
$input.on('keyup', keyUpListener);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. I want the listeners to be bound to the same element but I do have different events.

Comment: You will have to rearrange the above to sit in your function

Comment: Yes that works for `copy/paste` but what about `selecting an auto-completion option, Linux-style middle-click paste, drag-and-drop, and lots of other things`? `input` handles everything correctly.

Comment: Yeah there are endless possibilities on how to populate a textbox, unfortunately I cant offer any other suggestions.