# jQuery keyup event lagging on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox where a user can only enter numeric data. I'm using the following function on keyup of the textbox:

```
$('#ssn').keyup(function () {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    this.value = val;
});
```

The problem I'm running into is the lag when the user keys up on a restricted key, the character displays for a moment before it's replaced with the empty string. And holding down a key will display a stream of characters in the box until the key is released. Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I've tried different keyboard events like keydown or keypress and they didn't seem to behave any better.
Here is a fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/oxpy96g9/

Comment: The 'lag' is unavoidable as the `keyup` event doesn't fire until the key is released and the value is added to the input field.

Comment: 1. A slowdown is introduced through jQuery
2. A slowdown is introduced through repeated variable declaration
3. A slowdown is introduced through firing up the JavaScript Regex machine
4. Your code runs AFTER the user releases the key, which looks like a slowdown. All in all, you've written a mess.

Comment: Try listening to the `input` event instead... `$('#ssn').on('input', function () { ... });`

Comment: maybe just use keydown() ? https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Comment: If you don't care about any of the previous points, try hooking keyup and keydown both, that might cause the visualization you're looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event

Comment: can't you use `<input type="number"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>Converting my comment to an answer</sub>

Rather than listening to the `keyup` event, listen to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent) so that the event is fired when the value changes rather than when the key is released:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vj770p6a/)

```
$('#numbers').on('input', function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
});
```

Comment: Oh wait. I tried this in jsfiddle, but apparently it was lagging, so it didn't process my click on "run" button after I've edited it to check :D