# How to use a javascript function depending on if else?

Tags: javascript

How can I write...

```
If a user is typing in input1 
    then do stuff in this table
else if 
    a user is typing in input2 then do stuff in the other table
```

I'm new to javascript but I'm learning. The problem I'm having is finding the correct way to write the `if` and `else` conditions. What I have now doesn't work correctly but it helps illustrate my goal.

```
<div class = "search">
  <input type="text" id = "inputTRUE" placeholder="Search Bought">
  <input type="text" id = "inputFALSE" placeholder="Search In Use">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var lis = $(".cartInfosFALSE tr");
    var liss = $(".cartInfoTRUE tr");
    var list = $.makeArray(lis.map(function(k, v) {
                    return $(v).text().toLowerCase();
                }));
if (liss) {
    $("#inputTRUE").keyup(function() {
        var userInput = $(this).val();
        lis.each(function(index, value) {
            $(value).toggle(list[index].indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
        });
    });
} else {
    $("#inputFALSE").keyup(function() {
        var userInput = $(this).val();
        lis.each(function(index, value) {
            $(value).toggle(list[index].indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

EDIT: -Got rid of if/else but now a new problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var lis = $(".cartInfosFALSE tr");
    var liss = $(".cartInfoTRUE tr");
    var list = $.makeArray(lis.map(function(k, v) {
                    return $(v).text().toLowerCase();
                }));

    $("#inputTRUE").keyup(function() {
        var userInput = $(this).val();
        liss.each(function(index, value) {
            $(value).toggle(list[index].indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
        });
    });

    $("#inputFALSE").keyup(function() {
        var userInput = $(this).val();
        lis.each(function(index, value) {
            $(value).toggle(list[index].indexOf(userInput) >= 0);
        });
    });

</script>
```

The first keyup does nothing and the second one works correctly.

Comment: You don't need `if/else` for this. Just attach different `keyup` handlers to each input. They will each fire only when the user is typing into that input.

Comment: Both your `keyup` handlers are doing stuff in the same table, not in different tables like your question says.

Comment: Thanks for responding, quick question. Is the `keyup` handler `$("#inputFALSE")` (as an example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your `if/else` statement. This way an event listener is attached to each input and handled independently.

```
$("#inputTRUE").keyup(function() {
    // do stuff
});

$("#inputFALSE").keyup(function() {
    // do other stuff
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkzfxuwj/2/) example.

Comment: I did this but still it doesn't work correctly. The first keyup does nothing and the second one works though.

Comment: I'm not able to get a fiddle working at all. I'll keep trying though

Comment: What browser are you trying it in? Works for me in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge, Safari & Opera.

Comment: it's because I was missing a letter....Working great now though. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `if / else`, beter to use event listeners:

```
$('#inputTRUE').on('input', function () {
    // do something
});

$('#inputFALSE').on('input', function () {
    // do something else
});
```

little example here: https://jsfiddle.net/yk0sseL7/

(about using `keyup` and `input` events read here - [jQuery 'input' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event))