# IE Javascript values not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML range control, that using javascript passes values back to a HTML Class.

Please see the below code:

HTML

```
        <div class="userbox">
                <h3> Number of Users:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="usercount4">5</span><h3>
                <input type=range min=5 max=50  value="5" step=1 id=usercount4></input>
        </div>

        <div class="serverbox">     
                <h3> Number of Channels:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="servercount4">&nbsp;1</span><h3>
                <input type=range min=5 max=150  value="5" step=5 id=servercount4></input>                                                      
        </div>

        <div class="totalbox">  
                <h3>Total:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<h3>
                <span class="total4">£30</span><p style="display: inline"> &nbsp;&nbsp;/ month</p>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                    var total4;
                    var count4 = $('#usercount4').val();
                    var addToTotal4 = function(){
                        total4 += parseFloat(this.value, 10);
                    };

                    var compute4 = function() {
                        total4 = 0;
                        $('.option4:checked ,#servercount4 ,#usercount4').each(addToTotal4);
                        $('.total4').text('£' + (total4 + ($('#usercount4').val()*5)-($('#usercount4').val())).toFixed(0));             
                    };

                    $('.option4, #servercount4 , #usercount4').change(compute4);

                    $('#usercount4').on('input', function(){
                        $('.usercount4').text($('#usercount4').val());

                    });

                    $('#servercount4').on('input', function(){
                        $('.servercount4').text($('#servercount4').val()/5);
                    });

                    $('#usercount4').on('input', function(){
                    $('.total4').text('£' + (parseFloat($('#servercount4').val())+parseFloat(($('#usercount4').val()*5))));
                    });

                    $('#servercount4').on('input', function(){
                    $('.total4').text('£' + (parseFloat($('#servercount4').val())+parseFloat(($('#usercount4').val()*5))));
                    });

                });
```

The code works fine on Edge, Safari and Firefox. But on IE the total4 field updates but the usercount4 and servercount4 fields do not.

A working demo can be seen here (the code is from the last set of range controls on the page)

www.yellowsand.co.uk/#telephony

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event#17384341

Comment: Thanks but I am testing on IE 11, so the oninput event should be a supported function

Comment: I don't think so, there is no guaranty that IE will work for any standards.

Comment: It also doesn't explain why some of my values are updating and others are not. Thanks, but I don't think this is the answer I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {

                    var total4;
                    var count4 = $('#usercount4').val();
                    var addToTotal4 = function(){
                        total4 += parseFloat(this.value);
                    };

                    var compute4 = function() {
                        total4 = 0;
                        $('.option4:checked ,#servercount4 ,#usercount4').each(addToTotal4);
                        $('.total4').text('£' + (total4 + (parseFloat($('#usercount4').val())*5)-(parseFloat($('#usercount4').val()))).toFixed(0));             
                    };

                    $('.option4, #servercount4 , #usercount4').change(compute4);

                    $('#usercount4').on('input change', function(){
                        $('.usercount4').text($('#usercount4').val());

                    });

                    $('#servercount4').on('input change', function(){
                        $('.servercount4').text(parseFloat($('#servercount4').val())/5);
                    });

                    $('#usercount4').on('input change', function(){
                    $('.total4').text('£' + (parseFloat($('#servercount4').val())+parseFloat(($('#usercount4').val())*5)));
                    });

                    $('#servercount4').on('input change', function(){
                    $('.total4').text('£' + (parseFloat($('#servercount4').val())+parseFloat(($('#usercount4').val())*5)));
                    });

                });
```

> The variable `count4` is not used.

You should really consider refactoring your code!

Comment: Thanks, but what did you change, the code provided looks the same as the original? Also it works in the same way. Ok on Edge, but usercount4 and servercount4 values do not update.

Comment: Try the new version of the code I just modified. I changed some computing operations. I thought it could be the problem for IE because there was some hard conversions. But it seems this is the input event which does not trigger. I added change event handling. I do not know if it is going to do the job..

Comment: Glad if I could help!