# How can I execute a jquery function on entering text in html text input box?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML code like

```
<input type="text" class="input-box">
```

I want to execute a jQuery function when the inputbox is filled with 4 character.

For example, I type "ABCD" then the function will be executed and not for "AB" or "ABC" something like that. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind an event handler and check text length, based on the length call the function

```js
$('.input-box').on('input', function() {
  if (this.value.trim().length >= 4) {
    // call your function here
    doIt();
  }
});

function doIt() {
  alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-box">
```

Comment: Thanks, @pranav. Got what I want.

Comment: @ShafeequeS : glad to help you