# jQuery: keyup event for mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, click, keyup

I'm having a few issues getting a keyup event to fire on my iPhone, my code is as follows:

```
        var passwordArray = ["word", "test", "hello", "another", "here"];

        var test = document.getElementById('enter-password');
        test.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {

            if (jQuery.inArray(this.value, passwordArray) != -1) {
                alert("THIS IS WORKING");
            } else {}

        });
```

The idea being that as the user is typing into the `#enter-password` field, as and when they've matched a word in the `passwordArray` the alert will fire. This works on desktop, e.g. once you've entered `word` the function will fire straight away as soon as you've typed the `d`. Is there anyway to get this to work for mobile too?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add input event. It is an event that triggers whenever the input changes. Input works both on desktop as well as mobile phones

```
test.on('keyup input', function(){
  //code
});
```

You can check this answer for more details on [jQuery Input Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384264/1694185)

Answer (score 29):

There are three events you can use (but you have to be careful on how you "combine" them):

- **keyup** : it works on devices with a keyboard, it's triggered when you release a key (any key, even keys that don't show anything on the screen, like ALT or CTRL);
- **touchend**: it works on touchscreen devices, it's triggered when you remove your finger/pen from the display;
- **input**: it's triggered when you press a key "and the input changes" (if you press keys like ALT or CTRL this event is not fired).

The **input** event works on keyboard devices and with touchscreen devices, it's important to point this out because in the accepted answer the example is correct but approximative:

```
test.on('keyup input', function(){
}
```

On **keyboard based devices, this function is called twice** because both the events **keyup** and **input** will be fired.

The correct answer should be:

```
test.on('keyup touchend', function(){
}
```

(the function is called on **keyup** for desktops/laptops OR on **touchend** for mobiles)

or you can just simply use

```
test.on('input', function(){
}
```

but remember that the **input** event will not be triggered by all keys (CTRL, ALT & co. will not fire the event).

Answer (score 2):

The touchend event is fired when a touch point is removed from the device.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend

You can pass keyup and touchend events into the .on() jQuery method (instead of the keyup() method) to trigger your code on both of these events.

```
test.on('keyup touchend', function(){
//code
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add a input event. It works on both mobile and computer devices.

Comment: It would be good to add more information to your  response. See [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and try to update your answer