# SAPUI5 keyup event not working on Mobile device's browser

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I have this code running fine in browser, but when I tried to run on the mobile browser, it didn't work. Any good suggestion?

```
    var oTextArea = this.getView().byId("selectConditionAS");

    oTextArea.attachBrowserEvent("keyup", debounce(function() {
        var searchkey = oTextArea.getValue();
        console.log(searchkey);
    }
```

Comment: take a look to [jquery-keyup-event-for-mobile-device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989559/jquery-keyup-event-for-mobile-device)

Comment: I have seen this too, any good sample code in ui5? oTextarea.on(“keyup”) is not working...

Comment: have you tried oTextarea.on(“keyup input”)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Browser events if you have SAPUI5 events which does the same. if you are using **sap.m.TextArea** or **sap.ui.commons.TextField** then you can use their **liveChange** event.

```
var oTextArea = this.getView().byId("selectConditionAS");

  oTextArea.attachLiveChange(function(oEvent){
   var searchkey = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
   console.log(searchkey)
  });
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I want to detect when the user stop typing and execute the function after X milliseconds. Can I do that with the above code?

Comment: `attachLiveChange` triggers every keystroke, so you would use it exactly the way you would with the default browser method.