# Why isn't my js function working in computer but not in cellphone?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, input

I have to automatic focus next input element when a number has been entered.

My HTML:

```
          "<input id='num-1' class='inp-num' data-pos='0' type='text' maxlength='1' name='one' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' autofocus='autofocus'/>" +
          "<input id='num-2' class='inp-num' data-pos='1' type='text' maxlength='1' name='two' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)'>" +
          "<input id='num-3' class='inp-num' data-pos='2' type='text' maxlength='1' name='three' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)'>" +
          "<input id='num-4' class='inp-num' data-pos='3' type='text' maxlength='1' name='four' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)'>" +
```

And in my javascript I have:

```
  $('.inp-num').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
       $(this).next().focus();
     }
  });
```

This actually works fine, thing is when Im trying to use it on my cellphone, it keeps staying at the same input, doens't go to the next one. I really need help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: On what browser?  On what OS?  There isn't one universal environment for cell phones

Comment: ?? You mean your function works in a desktop computer, but not in a cellphone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery: keyup event for mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989559/jquery-keyup-event-for-mobile-device)

Comment: It works only in desktop, not in cellphones. I tested it on android and iOS (both in chrome app)

Answer (score 0):

The browser of your cellphone did not receive the value inside the input element before the `keyup` event is fired. Therefor `if ($(this).val())` is false at this time. You need to use another event type (like `input`) to avoid this.

Further information and a playground:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

```
$('.inp-num').on('input', function() {
 if ($(this).val()) {
   $(this).next().focus();
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tested but it doesn't work eighter :(

Comment: @JesúsV. sorry my bad - now i am using `input` event and this should work