# onkeyup, onkeydown and onpaste events not working on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, keyevent, onkeydown

I was working on some validations and I need to trigger some functions on onkeyup, onkeydown and onpaste events. However it is not working on Android mobile but working fine on the desktop.

```js
function limitInput(event, length) {
  const e = event;
  if (
    [8, 9, 13, 37, 38, 39, 40].includes(e.keyCode) ||
    (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 58) ||
    (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) ||
    ((e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true) && (e.keyCode === 65 || e.keyCode === 67 || e.keyCode === 86))) {
      /* Allow it */
  } else {
    /* No valid keyCodes */
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" onkeydown="limitInput(event, 4)" onkeyup="formatInput(event, 4, '/', 2)" onpaste="formatInput(event, 4, '/', 2, true)" required>
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not working on touch device, because touch devices doesn't have a Keyup or down. You should probably use an onchange or oninput listener.
Look here for further Event explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989559/jquery-keyup-event-for-mobile-device

Comment: @FloriandeVille, No its working fine on iOS devices. Only the issue is with the android devices.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use e.code instead of e.keyCode;

Based on MDN [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some
>   time. Instead, you should use KeyboardEvent.code

Replace it and see whether it's working or not. More info [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

Comment: Can you please help me showing , how to use event.code for numeric validations?

Comment: KeyboardEvent: key='s' | code='KeyS'
KeyboardEvent: key='s' | code='KeyS'
KeyboardEvent: key='d' | code='KeyD'
KeyboardEvent: key='2' | code='Digit2'
KeyboardEvent: key='2' | code='Digit2'
KeyboardEvent: key='3' | code='Digit3'
KeyboardEvent: key='4' | code='Digit4'
KeyboardEvent: key='5' | code='Digit5'

Comment: More info [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)