# How to fix jQuery 'length' of undefined problem in browser mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm create input form where user can add some text. if input value is empty, submit button is disabled, if text is entered submit button is enabled.
my created code is working well, but when I use mobile or Touch view (chrome dev. tools toggle device toolbar) is not working.I think problem is Touch but i cant solve it.

```js
$('#imgText').on('keyup keypress', function() {
  if($(this).val().length >= 1) {
      $("#generate-img").removeClass("no-click");
    }
});
$('#imgText').on('keyup', function() {
  if($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $("#generate-img").addClass("no-click");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: croppie-generator.js throws the error, not jQuery. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Who is "#imgText" and "#generate-img"? Please provide full code, I cannot help if I don't have all the data to reproduce the problem in jsFiddle. :(

Comment: If `$(this).val()` is undefined, just add this to your `if` statement: `if ($(this).val() && $(this).val().length >= 1...`

Comment: In addition, the second on-keyup could be an `else` block in the first one

Comment: There are no Keyup and KeyDown events available at mobile devices, you're event will never be fired on mobile devices. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989559/jquery-keyup-event-for-mobile-device/39031921

Comment: thank you for answering me. on("input", function() is work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's [`.on('input')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event) method instead to catch changes made to field's value.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#imgText').on("input", function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $("#generate-img").addClass("no-click");
    } else {
      $("#generate-img").removeClass("no-click");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.no-click {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="imgText">
<input id="generate-img" type="submit" class="no-click">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method for mobile devices

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#imgText').on("keyup input", function() {
    if($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $("#generate-img").addClass("no-click");
    } else {
      $("#generate-img").removeClass("no-click");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.no-click {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="imgText">
<input id="generate-img" type="submit" class="no-click">
```