# jquery function event not triggered on mobile device

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this jquery function that works fine on a desktop pc, but when running on a mobile device like iPhone this event is not triggered at all. Is there a workaround for that?

```
$('#myinputname').on('keyup change', function(c) {
  alert('test');
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: keyup event for mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38989559/jquery-keyup-event-for-mobile-device)

Comment: No it does not work