# js onkeyup does not work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

```
function SpaceFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("removespace");
  x.value = x.value.replace(/ /g, "");
}
```

and :

```
function Count() {  
    var i = document.getElementById("mylabel").value.length;  
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = 150 - i; 
}
```

why does not work on mobile devices? and What should I do?

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029711/9556193).

Comment: I had seen it before I asked question, but does not work for me too.

Comment: so, to make sure, `document.onkeyup=function(ev){document.write(ev)}` would have NO result?

Comment: no. please write your code specific for my codes

Answer (score 1):

Some mobile and virtual keyboards do not fire `keypress` events and use the [compositionupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/compositionupdate_event) event. I had this problem before and just had to add a listener for both `keyup` and `compositonupdate`