# On input event on form doesn't fire when checkbox changes

Tags: jquery, html, input

The title pretty much say it all. To reiterate, when I have the listener `.on('input',...` assigned to a form, the event fires for `<select>` and `<input>` changes, but it doesn't fire for checkbox changes.

Here's a fiddle of what I'm talking about:

https://jsfiddle.net/6vzftzum/

```
<form class='request-form'>
  <input type='text'>
  <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
  </select>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="not-completed" checked>Not Completed</label>
</form>

<div class='put-stuff-in-here'>

</div>
```

```
var i=0;
$(".request-form").on('input', function() { 

    $(".put-stuff-in-here").append(i + "<br>");
    i++;

});
```

Is there a way I can make a listener that will fire for all input changes in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` event won't fire the checkboxes, but we can handle it with a `change` event. Although we'll need to separate the listeners, we can have them call a mutual function so that any changes that need to be made to both only have to happen in one place.

```
function changeFunction(elem) {
    $(".put-stuff-in-here").append(i + "<br>");
    i++;
}

$('.request-form input[type="checkbox"], .request-form select').change(function() {
    changeFunction($(this));
});

$('.request-form input[type="text"]').on('input', function() {
    changeFunction($(this));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/6vzftzum/2/)

Comment: With this though, the event only fires once the element loses focus. Is this implementation possible with the same functionality of the `input` event (where the event fires immediately)? Or should I just make two separate events, one for `$(.request-form input').change` and another for `$('.request-form).on('input',...`?

Comment: @John I've edited my answer - you can use `input` just as easily!

Comment: Same issue as the start. The checkbox doesn't work with that https://jsfiddle.net/7efezaa1/

Answer (score 0):

The `'input'` event only fires when the text content is changed. Clicking a checkbox will not change the text within your form. See this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)