# $(this) not updating when changing focus

Tags: jquery

I generate inputs (with a max length of 1) dynamically using JavaScript so I don't have to type them all in manually. I made them such that when I type into them, they go to the next input and when I press backspace, they delete the value inside the input, then go to the previous one.

**Expected behaviour**

When I press backspace, it'll delete the letter, then go to the previous input.

**What actually happens**

When I press backspace, it'll delete the letter, then do this weird shuffle, and then I press backspace again, and then it moves to the previous input.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfLsaLqp/) that reproduces the issue I'm having.

Since Stack Overflow won't let me post this without code (here is the jQuery code):

```
function generateInputRows() {
  var inputHTML = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       inputHTML += '<div class="inputColumn"><input maxlength="1" type="text"><div>';
       inputHTML += (i + 1);
       inputHTML += '</div></div>';
     }
     inputHTML += '</div>';
     return inputHTML;
 }

function setUpTyping(){
    $('.inputColumn input').on('input',function(event){
        var inputs = $('.inputColumn input');
        var index = inputs.index(this);
        inputs.eq(index + 1).focus();
    });

    $('.inputColumn input').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val() == ""){
            var inputs = $('.inputColumn input');
            var index = inputs.index(this);
            inputs.eq(index - 1).focus();
        }   
    });
}

 $('#rows').html(generateInputRows());
 setUpTyping();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a lot of ways to solve this, such as tracking which input you are actively editing. However, for your current logic you just need to adjust the `input` event to check if the value is blank, before attempting to focus the next field.

```
$('.inputColumn input').on('input',function(e){
    var inputs = $('.inputColumn input');
    var index = inputs.index(this);
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        inputs.eq(index + 1).focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: I can't believe it was something that simple!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the same event for the logic as you can see in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfLsaLqp/1/)?

```
function generateInputRows() {
  var inputHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    inputHTML += '<div class="inputColumn"><input maxlength="1" type="text"><div>';
    inputHTML += (i + 1);
    inputHTML += '</div></div>';
  }
  inputHTML += '</div>';
  return inputHTML;
}

function setUpTyping() {
  $('.inputColumn input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val() == "") {
      var inputs = $('.inputColumn input');
      var index = inputs.index(this);
      inputs.eq(index - 1).focus();
    } else {
      var inputs = $('.inputColumn input');
      var index = inputs.index(this);
      inputs.eq(index + 1).focus();
    }
  });
}

$('#rows').html(generateInputRows());
setUpTyping();
```

Comment: That worked! Was the issue something to do with the separate `input` event?

Comment: @silverAndroid Yes - essentially it was the root of the "shuffle" you mentioned. Here's a good read on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event

Comment: They only down side here, is that things like shift/shift+tab will cause it move forward a box. Obviously there's other logic you could build in to prevent this, but just wanted to throw that out there. `keyup` isn't always the best, but it does have a lot of options to check.