# Best way to trigger jquery with range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my jquery...The function works well with other elements, but not with the range input. I want to calculate a value and I need to access other values for that

```
<input type="range" name="range" id="range" min="0" max="<?php echo $max_range; ?>" oninput="calc_happy()">
<input type="number" name="range" id="ranged" value=""oninput="calc_happy()">
<select name="work_value" id="work_value" onchange="calc_happy()">
  <option value="-1.0">Low work</option>
  <option value="-1.2">Easy work</option>
  <option value="-1.4">Normal work</option>
  <option value="-1.6">Hard work</option>
</select>
```

And here is the Js:

```
<script>
function calc_happy(){
    var selected = $('#work_value').val();
    var ranged = $('#range').val();
    var happy = Math.round(selected*ranged);
    var nhappy = <?php echo $happy-$wood_minus;?>+happy;    

    $('#w_stats td').eq(7).html(Math.abs(happy));
    $('#w_stats td').eq(5).html(selected);
    //calcul new happy
    $('p4').html(nhappy);
    $('p2').html(happy);

    if(nhappy <= 1){
        $('#img').attr("src","../design/images/stats/sad.bmp");
    }
}
</script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        $('#work_value').val('<?php echo $wood_w; ?>');
        $('#range').val('<?php echo $wood_minus/$wood_w; ?>' );
        $('#ranged').val('<?php echo $wood_minus/$wood_w; ?>' );
    }
</script>
<script>
    function putvalue(){
        $('#ranged').val($('#range').val());
    }
    function putvalue2(){
        $('#range').val($('#ranged').val());
    }

</script>
```

The script is working well for the select input, but not for the other triggers... Please, mind my poor coding, I appreciate any advice and notice it for future. Thanks!
Edit: and the piece of code

```
   window.onload = function() {
        $('#work_value').val('<?php echo $wood_w; ?>');
}
```

receive values from db which match with option values, but sometimes is working, sometimes not...even with multiple refreshes...

Comment: `oninput` event - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

Comment: Since you asked for advice on your coding, I would either use all jQuery stuff or not use it at all. I find code is clearer if you do the same sort of thing the same way. You can also embed `value="<?php echo $wood_w; ?>"` for the number and range input rather than using jQuery's `val`, though the select is a little trickier, so I see why you'd go down the `val` route.

Comment: Thank you, Don for help! You really simplify my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#range, #ranged, #work_value").on("change keyup input", calc_happy);
```

Here's the code. I added some debug code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#work_value').val('-1.4');
        $('#range').val('5' );
        $('#ranged').val('7' );

        $("#range, #ranged, #work_value").on("change keyup input", calc_happy);
    })

    function calc_happy(){

        var selected = $('#work_value').val();
        var ranged = $('#range').val();
        var happy = Math.round(selected*ranged);
        var nhappy = 12+happy;    
        
        var $result = $("#result");
        var $newDiv = $("<div />");
        $newDiv.text("selected: " + selected + ", ranged: " + ranged + ", happy: " + happy);
        $result.prepend($newDiv);

        $('#w_stats td').eq(7).html(Math.abs(happy));
        $('#w_stats td').eq(5).html(selected);
        //calcul new happy
        $('p4').html(nhappy);
        $('p2').html(happy);

        if(nhappy <= 1){
            $('#img').attr("src","../design/images/stats/sad.bmp");
        }
    }

    function putvalue(){
      $('#ranged').val($('#range').val());
    }
    function putvalue2(){
      $('#range').val($('#ranged').val());
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <input type="range" name="range" id="range" min="0" max="15" />
    <input type="number" name="range" id="ranged" value="" />
    <select name="work_value" id="work_value">
      <option value="-1.0">Low work</option>
      <option value="-1.2">Easy work</option>
      <option value="-1.4">Normal work</option>
      <option value="-1.6">Hard work</option>
    </select>
    
    <div id="result">
    
    </div>
```

Comment: sir, you are amazing! Thanks you, all for advices!

Comment: Happy to help! The one thing to watch out for with this approach is that the event handler can be called multiple times when the user changes the value, since the handler is called for `change`, `keyup`, and `input` events. While that's not a problem in this particular case, it would be if you were be doing something where repeating the handler would be bad (for example, sending an AJAX request that modifies data in a database).

Comment: I updated the fiddle to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/don01001100/91sn6bLr/1/

And take a look at this Stack Overflow answer for a little more discussion on the `input` event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384341/1102726

Answer (score -1):

Use `oninput` instead of `onchange`.