# jquery $.post action called 2 time

Tags: jquery, post

I use a jquery post to send data to a simple php page:

---

```
$( "body" ).on( "keyup", ".attribuzioneabbonamento", function(){
    var AbbonamentoCodice = $(this).val();
    var IdRiga = $(this).attr('dd');

        if(AbbonamentoCodice.length == 13){

                $.post("engine.php",
                {
                    Action: 'attribuisciabbonamento',
                    Code: AbbonamentoCodice,
                    IdRiga: IdRiga
                },

                function(data, status){
                    if(status == 'success'){
                        $('.abbonamentorisposta'+IdRiga).html(data);

                    }else{

                    }

              });


        }
});
```

---

It works, but the problem is that every time the post is executed 2 times.

Why is it called 2 times?

Comment: Presumably your `keyup` event is firing twice.  Or you have other code not shown here which is causing the problem.  Or perhaps you've made a mistake or false assumption in your debugging.  Can you clarify?

Comment: How are you determining the post occurs twice vs something occurring twice server side using one post?

Comment: i know is called 2 times return status change
first call
<div>success</div>
after 1 "micro" second print
<div> fail</div>

Answer (score 1):

Try this function. May be you are binding the same function twice somehow. So unbind the previous bound function with `off()`

The  `$( "body" ).off("input.myinput")` will unbind only your bound keyup function and not any other keyup events bound on body.

```
 $( "body" ).off("input.mykeyup").on( "input.myinput", ".attribuzioneabbonamento", function(){
    var AbbonamentoCodice = $(this).val();
    var IdRiga = $(this).attr('dd');

        if(AbbonamentoCodice.length == 13){

                $.post("engine.php",
                {
                    Action: 'attribuisciabbonamento',
                    Code: AbbonamentoCodice,
                    IdRiga: IdRiga
                },

                function(data, status){
                    if(status == 'success'){
                        $('.abbonamentorisposta'+IdRiga).html(data);

                    }else{

                    }

              });


        }
});
```

Comment: are you using shift+somekey at the thirteenth time?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17384218/4990572  try input event instead of keyup. may be this post is what your issue is

Comment: the input field its inserted in the page with a same call
Like

Comment: the input field its inserted in the page with another function using $.post is not present already in a dom of page

Comment: @NicolaLorenzini Did you try changing the keyup event to “input” event?

Comment: I'm trying to make a demo by isolating the code to see the behavior

Comment: Nandita Arora Sharma, i ve tried as u told me ...change keyup to input, that work!!! thx!! i dunno why i didnt found a bug just change and call only 1 time thxs to everyone guys!!!

Comment: Thanks – Nandita Arora Sharma

Comment: you are most welcoe @NicolaLorenzini :)