# jQuery change event does not trigger in my browser (in jsfiddle is does)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want that everytime a textbox gets changed that one function gets executed.
For this I have this code:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("tree");

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.id = 123;
input.type = "text";

div.appendChild(input);

$("input").change(function() {
  alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

It even works here in the "Run code snippet".

I use a new version of Chromium for this and I open the HTML file locally. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Check in console, if you have any error or not

Comment: Are you creating elements dynamically i.e. on button click or loading via ajax? Try `$('#tree').on("change","input",function() {`

Comment: @SudharshanNair I get no errors in the console

Comment: @Satpal Im Creating elements dynamicly inside  of $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: @JonDoe789. can you check in other  browsers as well. Paste your entire code

Comment: is that dom element or a live element ? Most of the time dom events does not work with live elements.

Comment: I got it, this is live element.

Answer (score 3):

Use `keyup` or `input` events instead `change`.

`change` event is only triggered on lost focus. [source](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: I only want to fire it when the user presses enter or leaves the textbox. Not with every key stroke.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Anyway, you can also listen to the `keydown` event, and check is it the enter key (keycode 13 if I'm not wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Please use blur event for triggering the event on leaving the textbox with change . Let me know if this helps you.

```js
var div = document.getElementById("tree");

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.id = 123;
input.type = "text";

div.appendChild(input);

$("input").on('blur',function() {
  alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tree"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine in Google Chrome : `Version 67.0.3396`

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    var div   = document.getElementById("tree");
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id  = 123;
    input.type= "text";

    div.appendChild(input);

    $("input").change(function() {
      alert("The text has been changed.");
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
  <body>
  <div id="tree"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:--

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('change keyup', function() {
        alert("The text has been changed.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 probleme here

- First: The event will not fire since .change not working on dynamic created items.
  Please refer to
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1207393/4798459

  > if your page was dynamically creating elements you would bind the event to a parent which already exists
- Second: The .change method is not really what you looking for. You might want to take input event, see more [jQuery 'input' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)

The code you need will be something like this. where the **first** parameter is the **event name** and the **second** is 
the child **css selector**

```
$("#tree").on("input", "input", funtion(){
    alert("The text has been changed.");
});
```

You can learn more about event delegation here : http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Also, if you assign a value in your code you might want to trigger input event to.

```
$("yourCssSelector").trigger("input");
```

It will trigger the **event** input