# Use jQuery to copy field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Case:

I'm building a form using Formidable Pro and I want to copy the value of one field to another using this code:

```html
<script>    
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#field_ttvo4').change(function(){ 
        var sourceField = $('#field_ttvo4').val();
        $('#field_4f0kv').val(sourceField);
        $('#field_4f0kv').trigger({ type:'change', originalEvent:'custom' });
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem:

This field looking up a value from the previous page of the form and it doesn't get copied in field_4f0kv. I have to remove the last digit, re-type it and leave ttvo4 before 4f0kv gets populated. Supposedly I'm using the wrong trigger but I can't figure out how to copy the field without altering ttvo4.

Comment: Use `.on("input", function () {` instead of `.change(function () {`

Answer (score 1):

If you want your value to copy over as you type, you should be using either the `input` or `keyup` events, [though `input` is probably better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#field_ttvo4').on('input', function() {
    $('#field_4f0kv').val($(this).val());
    $('#field_4f0kv').trigger({type: 'input', originalEvent: 'custom'});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="field_ttvo4" />
<input id="field_4f0kv" />
```