# Enter two digits between 0 and 59 after ":"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enter after : a value from 0 to 59 max. For example:

```
350:59
20:22
```

This code works but max after : is 99

```
$("#duration").on('input', function() { 
  this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\:?\d{0,2}/); 
});
```

Comment: Convert the string to a number and compare it.

Comment: theres already a ton of prebuilt time controls.

Comment: this `\d{0,2}/` only says that the last 2 digits have to be numeric, you can easily tell that the first can only be from `[0-5]` and the second from `[0-9]`, giving you 00 to 59

Comment: I tried this thing but it didn't work

Comment: why not? `/\d{1,}\:[0-5][0-9]/` -> https://i.imgur.com/3D0X1Qn.png

Comment: I tested your solution but it doesn't work with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

For values entered character by character, try this:

```js
$('#duration').on('input', function() { 
    this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\:?[0-5]?[0-9]?/); 
});
```

### Background

This kind of setup will depend heavily on what kind of input that is expected, and how the input value is entered. I.e. if it is being typed in, pasted as a whole or inserted by a function.

Your current solution is relying on the fact that we can assign the `match()` function’s result immediately as the input field’s value.

The [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function will return the following:

> An `Array` whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or `null` if no matches are found.

Consider an input of `"42:100"`

```js
const result = '42:100'.match(/^\d+\:?\d{0,2}/);
```

`match()` returns:

```js
["42:10", index: 0, input: "42:100", groups: undefined]
```

which we immediately assign back to the input field. It will opt to display the first item in that array, i.e. `"42:10"`.

If `match()` would not find a matching pattern then it returns `null` and the input field goes blank.

### Possible solution

So, with that info, we now know that if a human is typing the value one character at a time *it is important that the regular expression will always be able to match an expected pattern*, for every legal input value, so that it in turn can be assigned back to the input field.

From the original regex I take it you want to allow for any length number, that might be followed by a colon and then a two digit value that resemble seconds (i.e. 0 – 59 being allowed.)

The key here is to make also the last two digits optional by using the quantifier operator `?`.

One possible solution would therefore be to enable optional digits after the colon, confining them to 0 – 59, e.g.:

```js
$('#duration').on('input', function() { 
    this.value = this.value.match(/^\d+\:?[0-5]?[0-9]?/); 
});
```

But again, it all pivots on what kind of values that are expected and allowed to be entered into the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

As I said in the comments, you can specify what characters are you expecting, if you say it's from `00` to `59`, you can easily specify it

```
/\d{1,}\:[0-5][0-9]/g
```

- `\d{1,}` starts with a decimal number [0-9] that can have 1 or more characters
- `\:` followed by `:`
- `[0-5]` follow digit must be from 0 to 5
- `[0-9]` follow digit must be from 0 to 9

live example https://regex101.com/r/9Zq1Lm/1

---

you can also, copy paste the code below and execute in the browser console

```js
const regex = /\d{1,}\:[0-5][0-9]/g;
const str = `350:59
20:22
1:68
0:12
24:75`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but with jquery

$ ("#duration") .on ('input', function () {
                    this.value = this.value.match (/ \ d {1,} \: [0-5] [0-9] /);
                });  do not work

Comment: maybe with you, but [works fine with me](https://jsbin.com/raduna/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: yes your code works perfectly but in my case no because I want the control in the input  $( "#duration" ).on('input', function () {}

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with your code, but should be quite easy to adapt the working answer to whatever you're doing... and I think you should be safer with [`propertychange input`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17384341/28004) instead of just `input`

Comment: anyway thank you for your answers and if I find a solution I will publish it