# jQuery to change DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am testing a jQuery Library **MathJax** which gets Mathematics code in Latex format, and shows Mathematics expression in html.

MathJax works - two ways - \ [ `latex-code`\ ] and \ (`latex-code`\ ), in this code, jquery appends `<p>` tag, but I can not append, either \ ( \ ) or \ [ \ ] which are latex delimiters.

I want the textbox has only the latex command, not the delimiters, which will be good for handling and testing latex, basically web-math testing.

Can anyone, with jquery knowledge help this? This does require, some DOM manipulation.

**Objective**
Textbox should not contain any delimiters, the delimiters should be anyway added by other methods.

**Bonus: 1**
Can, button be removed - the jquery is to be updated on every input, and tries to render in every change of input

**Bonus: 2(can brake, not necessary)**
If possible, can there be two line, and after <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside textbox, the two expressions, get `\\` delimiter between them, which will show Mathematics expression, in next line

like: \sin(x)  \  \tan(x) {two backslash between \sin(x), \tan(x) commands}

```js
   $("#check").click(function (){
        $("#qPreview").empty().append("<p>" + $("#input").val() + "</p>");
        MathJax.typeset(["#qPreview"]);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
              <strong> Type Latex code Here :<br></strong>
<input type="text" id=input class="form-control" value="\(\frac{a}{b}\)">
<div id="qPreview"></div>
<button id="check">Click</button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify the functionality you're looking to have? I think the details of MathJax may be unnecessary, if all you are looking for is certain text/DOM to be moved or edited. Specifically, when you say "Textbox should not contain any delimiters", can you give an example of the input (presumably `\(\frac{a}{b}\)`) and your expected output (I'm guessing here, but maybe `frac{a}{b}`)?

Comment: yes - expectation is - `\frac{a}{b}` - I do not want to get rid of - slash of `frac`, this is latex command, which should remain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is to move the `\(` and `\)` outside of the input field and into `#qPreview` instead. Additionally, you need to escape the `\` in the prefix/postfix with another `\`. This keeps your `input` value as just `\frac{a}{b}`.

```js
let prefix = "\\(";
let postfix = "\\)";

$("#input").on('input', function() {
  $("#qPreview").empty().append(
    "<p>"
    + prefix
    + $("#input").val()
    + postfix
    + "</p>"
  );
  MathJax.typeset(["#qPreview"]);
}).trigger('input');
```

```html
<script id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<strong> Type Latex code Here :<br></strong>
<input type="text" id="input" class="form-control" value="\frac{a}{b}" autocomplete="off">
<div id="qPreview"></div>
```

Comment: Can there be working example without button? but your code does not work with this example `\(\require{color}\)\[\color{cyan}{sin(x)}_{\color{red}{\tan(x)}}\]`  - well in place of square bracket, there can be parentheses

Comment: Sure, updated. There's an `input` event (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384218/jquery-input-event) that will update on every input change. I also moved your MathJax script above jQuery so when the initial jQuery `.trigger('input')` on load happens, MathJax is already loaded.

Comment: ha just trying to spread the knowledge. For your example of `\(\require{color}\)\[\color{cyan}{sin(x)}_{\color{red}{\tan(x)}}\]`, could you again show what you'd expect to see in the `input` for this?

Comment: this particular example works straight - in the previous textbox - as the code use package - `color` - leave, all problems need not to solve - MathJax is not complete either, it is just for showing Maths - so many missing commands(which are given in LaTex by package though) - to Provide all examples by MathJax would be overkill though, cause it's just Math renderer, not actual latex - - for the given example - - input can not be replaced like previous example - where `\( \)` delimiter was blank, and appended, but here delimiter is already present - after package - `\[ \]`- this is delimiter