# If textarea contains this text then run query

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   if ($("#write_text_id").text() === "Saurav & Kunal Are God") {
      $(".submit_form_field").addClass('item-3');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <textarea id="write_text_id" class="textarea small" tabindex="105" placeholder="Write Saurav &amp; Kunal Are God" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input id="submit_btn_id" class="submit_form_field" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

I'm expecting that if I write "Saurav & Kunal Are God" in the textarea then submit button will add class `item-3`.

Comment: `textareaText.contains('Saurav & ...')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check when input typing and not one time. For this, with jQuery, you can use `on('input', function)` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17384218/10952503).

I personally remove the class when it's wrong, to make it disappear when the text change again.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#write_text_id").on('input', function (e) {
        if (e.target.value === "Saurav & Kunal Are God") {
           $(".submit_form_field").addClass('item-3');
        } else
           $(".submit_form_field").removeClass('item-3');
    });
});
```

```css
.item-3 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">
  <textarea id="write_text_id" class="textarea small" tabindex="105" placeholder="Write Saurav &amp; Kunal Are God" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input id="submit_btn_id" class="submit_form_field" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: @TheDestiny With pleasure :) Can you accept my answer with the check mark on top left ? :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an `EventListener` instead of `document.ready` to watch for changes to the textbox.

Notice that `document.ready` will only get called once from the `console.log` I added when the document is originally loaded:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("test");
  if ($("#write_text_id").text() === "Saurav & Kunal Are God") {
    $(".submit_form_field").addClass('item-3');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-a2yjHM4jnF9f54xUQakjZGaqYs/V1CYvWpoqZzC2/Bw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="test">
  <textarea id="write_text_id" class="textarea small" tabindex="105" placeholder="Write Saurav &amp; Kunal Are God" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input id="submit_btn_id" class="submit_form_field" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

However, upon using an `EventListener` you will get the desired result when clicking the submit button:

```js
$("#write_text_id").on("change", (event) => {
  if ($("#write_text_id").val() === "Saurav & Kunal Are God") {
    console.log("in if condition");
    $(".submit_form_field").addClass('item-3');
  }
});
```

```css
.item-3 {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-a2yjHM4jnF9f54xUQakjZGaqYs/V1CYvWpoqZzC2/Bw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="test">
  <textarea id="write_text_id" class="textarea small" tabindex="105" placeholder="Write Saurav &amp; Kunal Are God" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
  <input id="submit_btn_id" class="submit_form_field" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

It is also worth noting that I used `$("#write_text_id").val()` since the `.text()` was not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   $('#write_text_id').on('keyup',function(){
        if ($('#write_text_id').val() === "Saurav & Kunal Are God") {
        
          $(".submit_form_field").addClass('item-3');
        }
        else
        {
         $(".submit_form_field").removeClass('item-3');
        }
    });
```

```css
.item-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="test">
    <textarea id="write_text_id" class="textarea small" tabindex="105" placeholder="Write Saurav &amp; Kunal Are God" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input id="submit_btn_id" class="submit_form_field" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
```