# File input change event not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html

The jQuery file change event is not working in IE, yet works perfectly in Safari, Firefox etc. Can anyone tell me why this is?

```
<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
<script language="javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.m_file').live('change',function() {
        alert("Changed");
    });
</script>

<input type="file" name="m_file" id="m_file" class="m_file" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery: change event to input file on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208471/getting-jquery-to-recognise-change-in-ie

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

TRY:

```
$('.m_file').change(function(){
alert("Changed");
});
```

Comment: Any reason for docking this answer?

Comment: I'd imagine it's because this is no different to what the OP already has, and won't help. Look at the duplicate question links in the OP comments for the fix for this. Wasn't me who downvoted BTW.

Comment: Adding the input fields dynamically using jQuery . So "live" is needed.. Please help

Comment: Apart from the duplicate questions, could you provide some explanation for why `change()` should work where `live('change', ...)` fails?

Comment: @rajeeesh: `live` is not *needed* if you add elements dynamically. It is more convenient sometimes, that's all. You can always add event handlers once you created the element.

Comment: @Felix Kling I used .change() because it worked for me in code I wrote yesterday, in IE7+ and FF.  Using jquery 1.8

Comment: .live() is deprecated anyway, take a look at .on()

Comment: But what's the explanation? According to the documentation, it should work with `live` as well. *edit:* Apparently there are problems and using `delegate` or `on` should solve it as well.

Comment: @Felix Kling can you please give me a little help on event handlers ? thanks for the reply guys

Comment: @rajeeesh: Don't know what kind of help you expect. Have a look at the jQuery documentation of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and if you want to learn how events work in general, I recommend to read the [articles on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).