# One click file dialog in HTML

Tags: html, dialog

I am looking for a one-click solution that will call up a file open dialog and from that dialog, send the file name to the next page. I stole this code, but it requires 2 clicks to get to the next page:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ImportTOA.php" method="POST" accept="text/csv">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Upload Daily TOA Logs: <br /><input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

I don't need to upload the file, I just need to pass the file name that the user chooses.

Comment: "I stole this code", that sounds kinda bad...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to upload the file, just remove the enctype. The file name should get passed without the upload. Then you could submit the form on the `change` event on the file. I'll need to double check the documentation, but I think `change` fires on the file input.

Looks like IE might be a bit different: [Jquery: change event to input file on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie)

You don't even really need to "submit" the form, just grab the file name via javascript and do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  With a sufficiently narrow Google query, I found the answer.  Should anyone come along to read this thread, here's the code I borrowed that worked:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ImportTOA.php" method="POST" accept="text/csv">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Upload Daily TOA Logs: <br /><input name="userfile" type="file" onChange = "this.form.submit()" />
</form>
```