# FIle upload control onchange call javascript function but not access file in IE7, IE8,IE9?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

## Html code

```
   <input type="file" id="fileuplaod" onchange="readURL();"/>
```

## javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function readURL() {
  var myFileList = document.getElementById("loadfile");
        alert(myFileList.files.length);
        // loop through files property, using length to get number of files chosen
        for (var i = 0; i < myFileList.files.length; i++) {
            // display them in the div
            alert("Run"); 
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += "<br/>" + myFileList.files[i].name;
        }
}
</script>
```

all browser run but not in IE7,IE8,IE9

Comment: Possible solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie

Comment: Are you using File API of HTML 5, then its not supported in IE7,8,9

Comment: yes used file API...another way please give me?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you 
[Click here](http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly)

Following function works fine on IE call onchange();

```
function fireEvent(element,event){
if (document.createEventObject){
    // dispatch for IE
    var evt = document.createEventObject();
    return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
}
else{
    // dispatch for firefox + others
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
    return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

}

Comment: onchange(); function call but file not access...what can i do?

Answer (score -1):

```
// FileUpload Control Change Event--
<input type="file" id="fileUpload1" onchange="readPicUrl(this)">

// JavaScript --
function(input)
{
    if(input.files && input.files[0]){ var xPic = new FileRead(); xPic.readAsDataUrl(input.files[0]);  x.onload = function(e){ 
 $("#imageId").attr("src",e.target.result);
 }
 }
}
```