# get value from html input field on insert to src tag using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field in which I am inserting value through browse button now i want to copy that value from input field to an src tag so that i can preview the image which user has just uploaded

here is my code

```
<input class="text-input" type="text" name="logo" id="logo" onclick="tinyBrowserPopUp('image','logo','client_logos');"/>
```

I want to copy selected value from above input field to

```
<img src="myimage" />
```

Comment: Where is your current javascript code?

Comment: Add code. What have you done so far? What didn't work? This sound like something that should be done on the server-side, as simply inserting a filename into an `<input type="file" />` field doesn't 'upload' it.

Comment: You can't access files from user's file system directly. Read about FileReader API. Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VM7sy/ . Read [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Comment: $("input[name='logo']").change( function() {

}); i am using this but this works for input which we type through keyboard not works for select in my case

Comment: no actually the file axist already on server as you see I have included tinybrowser, on click function tiny browser uploads the file in my image directory and then return the path to input value name="logo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't directly show it from the user's computer instead you will need to first upload it to your server and then show it. Uploading the file using ajax would create the same effect you want. Also take a look at: [FileReader API @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

**Update:** As you have the image already on the server try the code below

Try this code:

**HTML:**

```
<input class="text-input" type="text" name="logo" id="logo" onclick="tinyBrowserPopUp('image','logo','client_logos');" />
<img src="myimage" />
```

**JS:**

```
setInterval(react, 5000);
function react() {
    document.getElementByTagName("img").src = document.getElementByName("logo").value;
}
```

Comment: no actually the file axist already on server as you see I have included tinybrowser, on click function tiny browser uploads the file in my image directory and then return the path to input value name="logo"

Comment: onchange works only when we type something in input field (through keyboard) in this case we are not gonna write anything we just select file from tinybrowser and then all of the path appears in input field onchange fails until we click in input box and write something

Comment: OK! let me check other methods as well! if you know one edit my answer I will approve it :)

Comment: can you post your tiny brows.... function please :) it would make it easier for me :)

Comment: yes y not here is the function
function tinyBrowserPopUp(type,formelementid,folder) {
tburl = "/admin/tinybrowser/tinybrowser.php" + "?type=" + type + "&feid=" + formelementid;
if (folder !== undefined) tburl += "&folder="+folder+"%2F";
newwindow=window.open(tburl,'tinybrowser','height=495,width=785,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}

Comment: try changing "type" in "tburl" to "img" instead of 'image'

Comment: I don't know either it's a good method or not but it works for me
setInterval(react, 5000); 
function react()
 {
 
 $('#im_preview').attr('src',$("input[name='logo']").val());
 }
after every 5 second interval react function execute and when it gets path it pass to src tag

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the img tag and use

```
var imagepath = $('#logo').val();
$('#myimg').attr('src', imagepath);
```

inside the function you fire when the input is changed

Answer (score 0):

I got this working with the code below.  I like to put the functions on body so that even if the class is added afterwards via AJAX the "change" command will still trigger the event.

My approach does use jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<input class="text-input" class="classhere" type="text" name="logo" id="logo" />
<div class="imagearea"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("body").on("change",".classhere",function(){
  //Equivalent of getElementById
  var fileInput = $(this)[0];//returns a HTML DOM object by putting the [0] since it's really an associative array.
  var file = fileInput.files[0]; //there is only '1' file since they are not multiple type.

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
       // Create a new image.
       var img = new Image();

       img.src = reader.result;
       $(".imagearea").html(img);
   }

   reader.readAsDataURL(file);//attempts to read the file in question.
});
```

This approach uses the HTML5 File System API's to read the image and put it into a new javascript img object.  The key here is readAsDataURL.  If you use chrome inspector you will notice the images are stored in base64 encoding.

**The reader is Asynchronous**, this is why it uses the callback function onload.  So make sure any important code that requires the image is inside the onLoad or else you may get unexpected results.