# Ajax Form is not working on IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#upload_photo').click(function () {
        $('input[type=file]#upload_myphoto').click();
    });
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=file]#upload_myphoto").change(function () {
        $("#node_profilepic").prop('src', 'loader.gif');
        $("#upload_profilepic").submit();

    });
});
$(function () {
    $('#upload_profilepic').ajaxForm({

        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,

        success: function (responseText, statusText) {
            alert(responseText);
            //$("#node_profilepic").prop('src',responseText);
            $('.iframe').click();
        },
        error: AjaxError
    });
});

function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    //alert(formData);
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    // alert(queryString);
    return true;
}

function AjaxError() {}
```

This code is used for uploading the image using Ajax call and it will work on all the browser except IE. Please tell me i can call the Ajax form using IE

Comment: What version of IE? What version of jQuery?

Comment: What your console saying?

Comment: Support for file transfers with Ajax was added with [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2), which is in IE 10 and later.

Comment: Why so many document ready statements?

Comment: Am using IE 10 and jquery-1.6.1.min.js. In alert box it is showing Undefined Index.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `setTimeout()` for `IE` like,

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=file]#upload_myphoto').change(function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#node_profilepic").prop('src', 'loader.gif');
            $("#upload_profilepic").submit();
        },100);// you can try 0 in place of 100
    });
});
```

Read [Inconsistent change event in IE](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11983) and [Jquery: change event to input file on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389341/jquery-change-event-to-input-file-on-ie)